# .NET Bitmap class unable to open LinkedIn profile images - any suggestions on how to open?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, image

I am trying to download a LinkedIn profile image into a .NET application. The application attempts to open the image, and either resize, crop, then resave the image into a PNG image format. The application loads the image into a stream. Then it tries to instantiate a .NET Bitmap type from the stream. The Bitmap type cannot instantiate, there is always a "Parameter is not valid" error that is returned during instantiation.

It seems all LinkedIn profile images cannot be opened by the native .NET Bitmap() APIs. I.e. my profile image is https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/wc_200_200/p/4/005/024/13e/11d2b5e.jpg. Images from other websites can be opened fine though. It seems possibly like the .NET graphics API does not natively support the LinkedIn jpeg format of profile images. In fact, saving the jpg locally and trying to open it using Windows native applications also fails.

How can I open and edit these images, either resizing, or cropping, etc.?

Error stack trace is below:

[ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.]
   System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Stream stream) +411353

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [WebP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/) image. Using ImageMagick's `identify` utility, I get:

> 11d2b5e.jpg WEBP 200x200 200x200+0+0 8-bit sRGB 4.44KB 0.000u 0:00.00

You'll have to use a library to read this image.  [Here is one](http://webp.codeplex.com/).

---

BTW, don't you just love GDI+ error messages?  This is the one that pops up for... well, pretty much every sort of error you can imagine.

Comment: Thanks Ed. That led me down the right path, although I'm using a different approach for my solution that I will add as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Ed S.' advice and analysis, I researched the WebP image encoding type at https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/?csw=1. There is an official Windows WebP codec available by Google for download at https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/download. Google's download page also offers a WebP to PNG converter as a Windows command line utility. So it would be possible to PInvoke that, possibly as a plan B alternative to a pre-packed .NET library.

After downloading the Google WebP codec, all native Windows graphics applications, such as Windows Photo Viewer, and the Windows Explorer Shell, are able to open and render WebP format images. However, the codec does not integrate natively into the .NET bitmap API, so a third party library like Ed S.' suggestion, or the Google WebP decoder command line utility via PInvoke, would do the trick.

I assumed that LinkedIn was serving .jpg files as the profile images have a .jpg extension. I won't necessarily know the true file type while trying to process a .jpg. I guess my development path of least resistance will be to use the native .NET Bitmap API first, and if it fails, attempt other image libraries such as WebP for .NET. I imagine there are more robust solutions to the problem.